# Looking for a S3 browser which supports Virtual-hosted style path in the requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, amazon-s3

I am working on developing a S3 client which is supposed to work in Virtual-hosted path style talking to different S3 servers. I need to analyse some HTTP headers in this particular mode, for which I need to use a S3 browser/tool (before I can implement my client) which can work in this particular mode.
I am aware of S3 browser and cloudberry, but looks like they do not have this support yet (Or may be I am missing out on something) ?
Is there any tool available for the same?

Answer (score 0):

I figured later, that Cloudberry browser also supports "virtual-host" path style mode. It needs to be toggled from their settings.list file.
Path 
OR
VHost